# Determine which callback responsible of triggering an event in Rails? after_save or before_destroy triggered the callback?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, callback

I have an ActiveRecord class Appointment:

```
class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_save :send_notifications
  before_destroy :send_notifications

  protected:

  def send_notifications
    if destroyed?
      logger.info "Destroyed"
    else
      logger.info "Confirmed"
    end
  end
end
```

Now the problem is that I'm trying to find a way to determine which callback responsible of triggering send_notification? the after_save or before_destroy? is there anyway to know how like if destroyed? I used here for demonstration ?

Thanks in advance

Eki

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure you can tell at this stage whether you're going to be destroying or saving the object.

You could invoke the callbacks slightly differently to capture that information though. For example:

```
after_save do |appointment| 
  appointment.send_notifications(:saving)
end
before_destroy do |appointment| 
  appointment.send_notifications(:destroying)
end

protected

def send_notifications(because)
  if because == :destroying
    log.info("Destroyed")
  else
    log.info("Confirmed")
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want different behavior in the two callbacks, I'd recommend dispatching through separate methods:

```
class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_save :send_notifications_on_save
  before_destroy :send_notifications_on_destroy

  protected

  def send_notifications_on_save
    send_notifications('Confirmed')
  end

  def send_notifications_on_destroy
    send_notifications('Destroyed')
  end

  def send_notifications(message)
    logger.info message
  end
end
```